# How to initialize array of pointers to functions?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have following code:

```
typedef int (*t_Function) (int x);
t_Function Functions[MAX_FUNCTIONS];
int f(int x)
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I cannot initialize it properly. If I add following line:

```
Functions[0] = f;
```

then compiler generates following error:

```
prog.c:217: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
prog.c:217: error: conflicting types for Functions
```

How to initialize this array of pointers to functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either do it inside a function, where `Functions[0] = f;` works fine, or with an array initializer:

```
t_Function Functions[MAX_FUNCTIONS] = {f};
```

For this to work, `f` (and all functions you want in `Functions`) must have been declared at the point where this definition appears. Note that all other `MAX_FUNCTIONS-1` elements of `Functions` will be `NULL` automatically if at least one of them is filled this way.