# fill an array of pointers to functions in another function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, call, fill

I tried to fill my array of pointer to functions in another function but I don't know how I can do it.

Below my function to fill the array

```
void* fill_tab_f(void (***tab_f))
{

    *tab_f[0] = ft_pt_char;
    *tab_f[1] = ft_pt_str;
    *tab_f[2] = ft_pt_ptr;
    *tab_f[3] = ft_pt_int;
    *tab_f[4] = ft_pt_int;
    *tab_f[5] = ft_pt_un_int;
    *tab_f[6] = ft_pt_hexa_min;
    *tab_f[7] = ft_pt_hexa_maj;
    
    return NULL;
}
```

Below the declaration of the array of pointers to functions and the call of the function to fill my array.

```
void(*tab_f[8])(va_list *, Variable*);
fill_tab_f(&tab_f);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why can't you do it? Does it fail to compile? Is there an error message? Does it just crash when you try to use it?

Comment: Having a triple-asterisk in the parameter, but then dereferencing your array members, seems a bit odd.  Why not just assign the function pointers directly?

Comment: Instinctively, it feels to me like you should be using array initialization here, not a runtime function.  This can all be done at compile time, unless your intent is to change out these functions at will during runtime.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071430/102937) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it

```
typedef int variable ;

void fill_tab_f(void (*tab_f[])(va_list *, variable *))
{

    tab_f[0] = ft_pt_char;
    tab_f[1] = ft_pt_str;
    tab_f[2] = ft_pt_ptr;
    tab_f[3] = ft_pt_int;
    tab_f[4] = ft_pt_int;
    tab_f[5] = ft_pt_un_int;
    tab_f[6] = ft_pt_hexa_min;
    tab_f[7] = ft_pt_hexa_maj;
}
```

or if function pointer syntax is a bit weird for you:

```
typedef int variable ;

typedef void (*funcptr)(va_list *, variable *);

void fill_tab_f(funcptr *tab_f)
{

    tab_f[0] = ft_pt_char;
    tab_f[1] = ft_pt_str;
    tab_f[2] = ft_pt_ptr;
    tab_f[3] = ft_pt_int;
    tab_f[4] = ft_pt_int;
    tab_f[5] = ft_pt_un_int;
    tab_f[6] = ft_pt_hexa_min;
    tab_f[7] = ft_pt_hexa_maj;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil does it matter considering the question?

Comment: @ChrisDodd well spotted. Too long week at work